# Win 8.1 transfer to Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, accessibility

I downloaded Ubuntu to my new Toshiba laptop, and at startup it asks which system I want to boot up, but Ubuntu will not boot.  What do I have to do to solve this? How do I partition the hard drive?

I am disabled and I want to use Ubuntu because it is smoother, and my voice typing software works seamlessly with it. I have win 8.1 right now and it is a nightmare for me.

I am a novice user and do not know a lot about managing the computer.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu did you download (12.04, 13.10)? How did you create the boot DvD or USB? What does the computer show on the screen when you try to boot Ubuntu? Is it just a black screen? Or does it show something like a error message?

Comment: did you disable secure and fast boot options in your bios?

Comment: please clarify your question by adding the info requested in the comment above. As it stands your question is to vague....